# alarm manager setting selected day to repeat. Am I doing it the correct way?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

users select the days and the time they want the alarm to trigger. Lets say user selects Sunday , Monday and Wednesday and the time to be 23:10. I set the alarmManager.setRepeating the intervals to be 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 which is 7 days. **Am I doing it in the correct way?**

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,getDay());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Don't see why that wouldn't work. May not be the best or most efficient way, but it should work. It might have scaling issues and might not be exact.

Comment: what do you mean by most efficient way?

Comment: You are setting the alarm manager to repeat at a rather large integer number. You could change that to AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7 and likely help efficiency. Depending on how exact it needs to be, you could also do setInexactRepeating using that constant which also, apparently, boosts efficiency.